# How to place images around wrapper without activating horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, background, scrollbar, wrapper

I have a webpage inside centered fixed width container (wrapper) and need somehow to place background images around (from left and right side of the wrapper) as is depicted on this image:

[image]

It is important not to activate horizontal scrollbar if browser window is too small to display whole background images, instead it should hide part of images on both sides.

My current wrapper is defined like this (but can change it if needed):

```
.wrapper { width:1000px; margin:0 auto;}
```

I've seen it on a lot of websites, is there any non-crazy way to achieve that?

Comment: can we see your HTML setup? are you using background-images or <img> tags?
a fiddle would be nice

Comment: I will use whatever tags or background-images that will work for this.

Comment: you can always simply hide the overflow: [https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/p6krkc6f/](https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/p6krkc6f/)... will this do the trick for you?

Comment: Yes, this works. Here is your modified example to demonstrate what exactly I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/p6krkc6f/4/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think from what I'm understanding that responsiveness is quite key for you here. Instead why not think about using two absolutely positioned divs? You can make them fully responsive quite easily taking advantage of background-image:cover as well.

See fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jsn3gpLn/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
    left: 10%;
    top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I mean, becouse I need 2 images, not just one. Here is the way how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/p6krkc6f/4/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could add a background-image to the body tag and then set the background-size to cover. Background-image does not activate any scrollbars. .

```
body {
  background-image:url("image.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution thanks to @Ben Filip comment:

```
html {
 background-color:#eee;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

#wrapper {
 width:200px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color: #fda;
 height: 350px;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
}
#wrapper:before{
 position:absolute;
 left:0; top:20px;
 margin-left: -182px;
 content:url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSu4GtZT0CIzTZmle8ARJUnwxKgd_0QKzmNt4KqRlAsL04devgFMw);
}

#wrapper:after{
 position:absolute;
 right:0; top:20px;
 margin-right: -182px;
 content:url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSu4GtZT0CIzTZmle8ARJUnwxKgd_0QKzmNt4KqRlAsL04devgFMw);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p6krkc6f/4/